# stopService() does not go into onDestroy()

Tags: android, service

Here are the code related to my question
//activity

```
Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startService);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UnbindService.this,StartService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
});

Button endButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopService);
endButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UnbindService.this,StartService.class);
        stopService(intent);
        System.out.println("312");
    }
});
```

//service

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){

    Log.d("DEBUGSERVICE", "Stop Button pressed");
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();

    System.out.println("in on destroy");
    handler.removeMessages(0);
    Toast.makeText(this,"end server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I try to debug with some println(), and found that when I click stopService button, it does not go to the onDestroy function. Anyone knows what happen there?

Comment: I tried with your code, Its woking fine.
Log, println is working fine.

Comment: @richardrun Sometimes if you cancel timer, it will not stop.

But its guaranteed, service will get on destroy callback once you call stopservice or stopself.

Comment: @KeyurThumar what do you mean it will not stop?

Comment: sometimes cancel method of timer will not stop your timer.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on `Phan Van Linh's`answer, I came to learn that your timer keeps going and toasting message.

I've tested your code and no error found.

Declare a global `boolean` variable that will hold whether the service is running. Within destroy set the value `false`. And check the boolean `value` before toasting

Comment: just checked if the service is running. Found that the service is not running after I press button to stop the sercive, but the handler (inside the service) still toasting message on my activity.

Comment: You got the solution but I'm writing as this may help for other users. Stop the `handler` based on a boolean value that indicates the service status.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
 public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
Log.d("DEBUGSERVICE", "Stop Button pressed");
timer.cancel();
timer.purge();

System.out.println("in on destroy");
handler.removeMessages(0);
Toast.makeText(this,"end server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

try this.

Here is a documentation for it.

the service's onDestroy() method is called and the service is effectively terminated. All cleanup (stopping threads, unregistering receivers) should be complete upon returning from onDestroy().

Answer (score 0):

My two thoughts on this:

1. From the Timer's docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()), calling `Timer#cancel` discards only scheduled tasks. The cancel method **does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists).**
   Having said that, holding strong references to your service in your Timer's task *could* prevent it from being destroyed.
2. According to [Android Service docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle),

> If the service is currently executing code in its onCreate(), onStartCommand(), or onDestroy() methods, then the hosting process will be a foreground process to ensure this code can execute without being killed.

Therefore you could be executing long running code in the above methods (at the beginning of the service) that delay `onDestroy` being called (though it's eventually called when the ***intent*** passed to `stopService(<intent>)` is finally delivered).